# Thin down jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have been optimizing my website but the one problem that stands in my way is all the jQuery functions that I do not use. The only ones that I use are for a smooth page scroller. It just seems like such a waste of download time.

My question is: Is there any script or program that will remove the jQuery code that I do not need and leave the 1 or 2 functions that I do need.

Comment: Keep in mind that with the ubiquitous nature of jQuery these days, if you use a CDN as Josh suggests, it is likely that the client will very rarely ever actually fetch the script. You are pre-pre-pre optimizing. Waste of time and effort in my opinion

Comment: jQuery when minified and gzipped is 24kB. Small enough to count as standard overhead nowadays. Not to even mention the caching benefits you get from using Google's CDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this, especially since it's not that simple.  For example `.fadeIn()` is one method, but it calls the whole animation section of jQuery to fade the element, but that's after your selector has accessed the traversal section including the Sizzle selector engine...that's how most frameworks are, it'd be *very* tricky to remove pieces because of so many dependencies inside the framework itself.

That being said, if you're delivering jQuery correctly, it's minified and gzipped, and you're only sending about **24kb** to the client *which they cache* so it's just sent once, not every page load.  Also, they may have already cached it from another site, the more people who point their site to the same CDN (the page you're viewing does) the more likely this is to happen.

Google has a CDN, [details here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/), for example from there you can grab jQuery, or jQuery UI:

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js
- Previous versions of these as well

Also, Microsoft has a CDN, [details here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/cdn.ashx), you can fran jQuery and the validation library from it:

- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
- http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.js
- [Full list of validation files here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDNjQueryValidate16.ashx)

Note: these are the current versions **as of the time of this answer**, don't use these explicit links if you're finding this later, there may be more recent versions available.

Answer (score 2):

Just reference the library from Google, chances are it will already be cached on the client...

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

This will also save you bandwidth.  StackOverflow and many other sites do this.

Comment: Plus, jquery really is pretty tiny which served up with gzip...not worth worrying about

Comment: @Billy - no worries, skynet is here to stay.

Comment: The problem with relying on caching is that many browsers invalidate cache on some requests much more than is desired or expected. Even with all headers set correctly to induce caching, most browsers will ignore caches for even a soft reload, or where a page hasn't finished loading (eg stalled) and the user initiates a subsequent request to the same resource.